# How to get music to play in Delphi 7?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, background-music

I need to get music to play in the background in the start of the program in the OnFormActivate event for my program. I have the song I want to use but I dont know what command Delphi needs to use in order to start playing that song.

Thanks for you help guys :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to play a wav-File in Delphi?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246723/how-to-play-a-wav-file-in-delphi)  You don't really need the MediaPlayerComponent, you can also use the MMSystem unit, see the link.

Comment: @Johan Does that also work for `wma` and `mp3`?

Comment: I used the TMediaPlayer and it works but after the length of the song, it does not repeat the song. How do I get the song to repeat ?

Comment: @NGLN, annoyingly sometimes it does and sometimes it does not. On my old laptop WinXP-xp3 it works with MP3's and on a VM-copy of my pre-pre laptop Win XP sp1 it does not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the TMediaPlayer component, it's on the System tab of the component palette.

```
procedure TForm1.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MediaPlayer1.FileName := '<fill in>.mp3';
  MediaPlayer1.Open;
  MediaPlayer1.Play;
end;
```

Set the `Visible` property to False.

---

**Edit** in response to OP's comment:

To repeat the song, you can use the TTimer component, also found on the System tab. To repeat the song with a one second delay:

```
procedure TForm1.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MediaPlayer1.FileName := '<fill in>.mp3';
  MediaPlayer1.Open;
  MediaPlayer1.TimeFormat := tfMilliseconds;
  Timer1.Interval := MediaPlayer1.Length + 1000;
  MediaPlayer1.Play;
  Timer1.Enabled := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MediaPlayer1.Play;
end;
```

Set the timer's `Enabled` property to False.

Comment: Some editions of Windows (N versions) in Europe have no MediaPlayer.
So you have to list it as requirement in the install script.

Comment: You don't need to run the Timer while the audio is playing. Set the `TMediaPlayer.Notify` property to true before calling `Play()`, then use the `OnNotify` event to detect when playback stops. Then start the timer for 1s and call `Play()` when it elapses.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `TMediaPlayerComponent`.
[Here](http://delphi.about.com/od/multimedia/l/aa112800a.htm) you can find a tutorial on how to use it.